# Where do I find my Google Font API Key? (Newbie)

Tags: wordpress, fonts, google-font-api, woothemes

I am working on a Wordpress site.
Woothemes framework, Canvas theme from Woothemes.
Have installed the plugin Google Webfonts for Woo Framework.
So far - so good.
Now I need a Google Font API key.
So I have a registered developer account, and a Google Font project up and running via GoogleCloud Console. I have activated the Google Font API in the API list.
But I can't find my Google Font API Key!
I've followed the instructions as given here: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api
It says:
"To acquire an API key, visit the APIs Console. In the Services pane, activate the Google Fonts Developer API; if the Terms of Service appear, read and accept them. (Edit: Done this!)
Next, go to the API Access pane. The API key is near the bottom of that pane, in the section titled "Simple API Access."(Can't find this at all!)
Any ideas?
Sorry if this is a terribly simple question!
Kind regards
Annelie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I hope you get your question answered. From my experience, I can't say with confidence that going to Google Groups -- even one dedicated to this product -- would be better than asking here.

Comment: Ah okay! :S
Thanks for letting me know! I will do so!

Comment: Just to clarify ... in my opinion I think it is *good* that you are asking here. I am *not* thinking you'll get a better answer in Google Groups. I was sympathizing with you. :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the help page is a bit behind and refers to the 'old' console.

Old: https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect
New: https://cloud.google.com/console?redirected=true

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the documentation, which will be in releases after 1.3.3 of the plugin the OP is using.

Comment: This plugin has moved on now. You don't need to provide your own API key - it uses a shared API key for all installs. It also has a hard-coded list of available fonts for when the API cannot be reached when in the admin page. I try to keep that list updated regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the *Google Webfonts for Woo Framework* plugin, found at http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-fonts-for-woo-framework/

For the last few versions, you do not need to use a Google API key to be up and running. The WordPress plugin contains a fallback list of all available Google webfonts, and I try to keep that list up-to-date as Google releases additional fonts.

So, unless there is a really new font you want to use, just run the plugin without an API key and it should provide all the Google Webfonts you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi at first create a project in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) then [go there](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api) and click on the "Get a Key" at the main of the page choose your project and get it.